View inside arabic text positioning issue react native
I have a text in arabic example : 'هذه نص عشوائي باللغة #'
and my code is replacing the # with a Animated.View component .
but in IOS the view is going on top of the text rather than in the # area
I tried to position absolute and also to change the font but it's not working

Please share some code, a screenshot of how you would like things to be and how they look like now. I can also recommend inspecting the view hierarchy to see why the behavior you are seeing happens.
